# Data does not refresh in browser but does in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a working submit button, so when I make changes to my form  and click submit the form updates to the changes...

HOWEVER. In the database it shows the new data. But when I RedirectToAction to the last page it doesn't show the updated data.

This is my code (Controller):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(M2Portal.Areas.Admin.Models.Users.Roles roleForm)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var role = Srvctx.Roles.FirstOrDefault(w => w.RoleID == roleForm.RoleId);
            role.RoleDescription = roleForm.RoleDescription;
            Srvctx.SubmitChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("RoleManagement");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("RoleManagement");
    }
    catch
    {
        return RedirectToAction("RoleManagement");
    }
}
```

so when it hits:

```
                     return RedirectToAction("RoleManagement");
```

it just goes to the page but doesnt refresh the data. but when i look at my database its been changed there.

Am new to ASP.NET MVC and have no idea where to start looking...

Any ideas?

role mangagement:

```
  public ActionResult RoleManagement(string userName)
    {

        return View("RoleManagement", new UserForm(userName));
    }
```

Rolemangement cshtml:

```
   @foreach (M2DAL.M2Service.Role r in Model.AllRoleIDs)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@r.RoleName</td> //This is not refreshing, on debug shows the number, but browser shows old number)
        <td>@r.RoleID</td>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit Roles", "EditRole", "Users", new { roleId = r.RoleID }, new { @class = "action" }) </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Post the code for the `RoleManagement` method - that where the issue is(and do you really want to also redirect to `RoleManagement` when the model is invalid as opposed to returning the view?)

Comment: iv added the rolemangement, this is just a cshtml page

Comment: `RoleManagement` method expects a parameter `userName` but your not passing anything to the method. Not sure what `new UserForm(userName)` does but `userName` is going to be `null`. When you redirect it should be `return RedirectToAction("RoleManagement", new { userName = "SomeValue" });` (and presumably  `userName` is the value of one of your properties in `Roles` when you posted the form)

Comment: when i debug, Username does show null, but when in the cshtml the RoleName shows as new data. but forsome reason it doesnt in the browser!

Comment: Hard to say. I don't even know what `new UserForm(null)` does. And looking at your previous question, `AllRoleIDs` is a property of type `Role` yet `RoleManagement` returns a model of type `UserForm` so do both types have property `AllRoleIDs`? I really don't know what your doing here. (ps. putting methods inside your models to access the database is not very good practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post the code for `RoleManagement` action. I don't know where are you storing your model, but are you sure, that this action is reading the DB again ?

There should be something like (just an example)

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult RoleManagement()
{
    var roles = Srvctx.Roles.Take(1000);
    return roles;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by .Take(1000) also i dont understand why it doesnt refresh would it be because of the RoleManagement method or the Save button?

Comment: As @stephen-muecke is saying, what exactly is behind `new UserForm(userName)` ? 
It looks like you are not loading any data from DB in your `RoleManagement` action.